# C++ last_write_time compared to Python

Tags: python, c++, porting

I am porting a line of Python to c++ that deals with looking at file modified times. Because only later versions of C++ have the support for filesystem, I thought I would use boost and for legacy compatibility reasons I am using I am using Boost 1.64 filesystem. My port of  `os.path.getmtime` is `boost::filesystem::last_write_time`. Python returns a fractional value while the implementation-dependent `last_write_time` returns a whole number in OSX 10.14.6 XCode  11.0.

The code is:

```
def GetModifiedTime(fileName):
    return os.path.getmtime(fileName)
```

and returns `1597265166.4072416` while the c++ code is

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::filesystem::path p = argv[0];
    auto v = boost::filesystem::last_write_time(p);    
    return 0;
}
```

and returns `1597265166.0`.

I would like these two return values to match.

My belief is that the `boost::filesystem` will be largely compatible with `std::filesystem`. The [last_write_time](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#last_write_time) function

> Returns: The time of last data modification of p, determined as if by
> the value of the ISO/IEC 9945 stat structure member st_mtime  obtained
> as if by ISO/IEC 9945 stat().

in an [std::time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) structure where the link says:

> Arithmetic type capable of representing times. Although not defined,
> this is almost always an integral value holding the number of seconds
> (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC, corresponding
> to POSIX time.

Which is unfortunate because I would like those fractional seconds back. Is `last_write_time` simply the wrong thing to use?

Comment: Those two values you posted are the same, i.e. the python vs c++ values.

Comment: Please, check your C++ result. According the documentation (and my test on ms windows): last_write_time returns integer value.

Comment: So, if you want to get the same values (python and c++), you should use another (may be OS specific) API. And last_write_time is wrong thing for your requirements.

Comment: Note: Boost went with the lowest common denominator in order to get the widest spread. The standard library went with [`timepoint` from `chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). You can have a lot of fun with `timepoint`s, including beating them into nanoseconds and from that converting to floating point is child's play. Note that the underlying OS may not provide fractions.

Comment: @Algebra8 oopsie. that was my mistake and fixed.

Comment: Maybe one of them is adjusting for time zone?